# Django transaction rollback on HTTP error responses

Tags: django, orm, transactions, decorator, httpresponse

All the [django transaction stuff](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/) rolls back the transaction if the view code throws an exception. How can I get it to roll back if I return an `HttpResponse` with an error status code, i.e. 4xx or 5xx as well?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I haven't tested this *at all*, and I have no idea if it is correct, but something like this may work. I'd appreciate any feedback!

```
from functools import wraps
from django.utils.decorators import available_attrs
from django.db import transaction
from django.http import HttpResponse

def commit_on_http_success(function=None, using=None, successStatuses=[200]):
    """Like commit_on_success, but rolls back the commit if we return an HttpResponse
    with a status that isn't 200 (by default).

    Args:
        using: The database to use. Uses the default if None.
        successStatuses: The HTTP statuses for which we will commit the transaction.
    Raises:
        It can raise an exception that overrides the view's exception if commit() or
        rollback() fails.
    """

    def decorator(view_func):
        @wraps(view_func, assigned=available_attrs(view_func))
        def _wrapped_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
            try:
                transaction.enter_transaction_management(using=using)
                transaction.managed(True, using=using)

                exc = None
                commit = False
                try:
                    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
                    if isinstance(response, HttpResponse) and response.status in successStatuses:
                        commit = True
                except Exception, exc:
                    pass

                if transaction.is_dirty(using=using):
                    if commit:
                        try:
                            transaction.commit(using=using)
                        except:
                            transaction.rollback(using=using)
                            raise
                    else:
                        transaction.rollback(using=using)
            finally:
                transaction.leave_transaction_management(using=using)

            if exc is not None:
                raise exc

            return response
        return _wrapped_view

    if function:
        return decorator(function)
    return decorator
```